# GIT : "git-upload-pack: command not found" while pushing to remote server

Tags: git, unix, version-control, ssh

So I'm using GIT, trying to push code to my remote server.

- on a shared unix hosting, and I'm not allowed to have my own environment variables (blocked for SSH accounts) and no sudo access.
- managed to install git successfully in my /home/
- trying to push code to the server returns : bash: git-upload-pack: command not found
- $PATH variable is set - because git is installed in my /home/
- to get things working, I had to use to following clone command :

  git clone -u /home/bin/git-upload-pack user@server.com:mygitfolder
- same versions of git on local machine/remote server (1.7.0.4)

so from what I can gather, I need to basically :

- find a way to either wrap my environment variable every time I push to the server
  or
- specify the path of my git-receive-pack while pushing to the server

I understand I could create a hook that would take effect as I push, but have not managed to find where/how this is implemented.

(I would rather not create an alias on my local machine)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you can not adjust the effective PATH on the remote side<sup>1</sup>, then you will have to specify the location of the programs from your local side.

As you found, [`git clone`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) can be given `-u /path/to/git-upload-pack` (or `--upload-pack /path/to/git-upload-pack`).

[`git fetch`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fetch.html) and [`git pull`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pull.html) accept `--upload-pack /path/to/git-upload-pack` (not `-u`, however, since it means something else to these programs). They also check the `remote.<name>.uploadpack` configuration variable.

[`git push`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html) accepts `--receive-pack /path/to/git-receive-pack` and checks the `remote.<name>.receivepack` configuration variable.

Once you have your repository cloned, you can use the configuration variables to record the paths:

```
git clone -u /home/bin/git-upload-pack user@server.com:mygitfolder
cd mygitfolder
git config remote.origin.uploadpack /home/bin/git-upload-pack
git config remote.origin.receivepack /home/bin/git-receive-pack
```

Then you can push, fetch, or pull without having to specify the path.

---

<sup>1</sup>
You said that “environment variables [are] blocked for SSH accounts”. If you mean that the *sshd* has its `PermitUserEnvironment` setting turned off (meaning that you can not use `environment="PATH=/home/bin:/usr/bin:/bin"` in your `.ssh/authorized_keys` file), then you still might be able to modify your default PATH via a shell initialization file (e.g. `.bashrc`).

Comment: A) This looks right, I'm away from my terminal but will try it asap
B) Yes to PermitUserEnvironment turned off for sshd accounts - thanks for the rectification :)