# Eclipse Git Push to Upstream Wrong

Tags: eclipse, git

I clone https://github.com/java093/springside4.git
and commit local changed files success in eclipse.Then I use  Team->Push to Upstream it show wrong:
 **An internal Exception occurred during push: https://github.com/java093/springside4.git: git-receive-pack not permitted**

how can i resolve this problem.It was successed in my other PC use the same git url(https://github.com/java093/springside4.git).

1. my eclipse version eclipse-jee-helios-SR2-win32.
2. I have set SSH Keys in my github account about this notebook. but how can i checked it has been successed set.
3. where can i find the **git-receive-pack not permitted** logs.

Comment: I found my question should be "How do I recover my SSH key passphrase? " https://help.github.com/articles/how-do-i-recover-my-ssh-key-passphrase. 
To make sure everything is working you'll now SSH to GitHub.
$ ssh -T git@github.com;

Comment: And u can audit your SSH keys https://github.com/settings/ssh/audit/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you are using the same remote address for your upstream repo on your "other PC":

You can use:

- an https address, like you did: but then your ssh keys won't be involved
- an ssh address: `git@github.com:[repo_owner_username]/[repo_name].git` and use a config file as [illustrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10724708/6309).

The bottom line is: if you expect using your ssh keys, you must use an ssh url, not an https one (which would use the GitHub credentials, ie your GitHub login and password, using a `_netrc` on Windows or `.netrc` on Unix as mentioned in "[Syncing with github](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5378094/6309)", not your ssh keys).

As the OP mentions below, the issue in this instance was similar to what [bb describes](http://www.bluehostforum.com/showthread.php?20304-Bluehost-Solution-to-the-Git-PATH-issue-when-using-a-non-interactive-shell):

> Solution to the Git PATH issue when using a non interactive shell

### > On Linux

```
git config remote.origin.uploadpack '/home/<user name>/bin/git-upload-pack'
git config remote.origin.receivepack '/home/<user name>/bin/git-receive-pack'
```

(or, considering the git installation path on the server in the OP's case:

```
git config remote.origin.uploadpack '/home/bin/git-upload-pack'
git config remote.origin.receivepack '/home/bin/git-receive-pack'
```

)

### > On Windows

```
git config remote.origin.uploadpack 'libexec/git-core/git-upload-pack'
git config remote.origin.receivepack 'libexec/git-core/git-receive-pack'
```

> The above solution works well, but assumes you already have a local git repo that is tracking a remote repo on the server.
>   **Cloning a repo will fail with the same error**.

```
git clone -u /home/<user>/bin/git-upload-pack <user>@<host>:/<path-to-repo>
git clone -u /home/bin/git-upload-pack <user>@<host>:/<path-to-repo>
```

Comment: Tahnks a lot.This problem is because the git-receive-pack(push) command not right setting.I have resolved it by:
git config remote.origin.uploadpack /home/bin/git-upload-pack

Answer (score 2):

Thanks a lot.This problem is because the **git-receive-pack**(push) command not right setting.
  I have resolved it by: **git config remote.origin.uploadpack /home/bin/git-upload-pack**

[GIT : "git-upload-pack: command not found" while pushing to remote server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6037707/git-git-upload-pack-command-not-found-while-pushing-to-remote-server)

Comment: +1. Good feedback. I have included in my answer additional elements.

Answer (score 0):

In most of the cases it is due to missing authentication details:

1. Open configuration.
2. click change button against URI field.
3. On change popup window make sure your URI path is like: 
   "https://github.com/[repo_username]/[repo_name].git"
4. select https protocols
5. Add repo_username and password.

Hope it will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you got the "write" access to this repository.

Answer (score 0):

I found exactly the same problem when I tried to make changes to the repository: **An internal Exception occurred during push: https://github.com ..............git: git-receive-pack not permitted)**.

In my case, it turned out that we in the team use the free version of Gitlab, which has a limit on the number of active members.
After the Repository Owner reduced the number of active members to 5, the problem was solved